# Updating Service Catalog Product Versions Through AWS CLI/Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-service-catalog

I want to automatically roll out new versions of my Service Catalog product using a Lambda that runs weekly. I can't find a corresponding Boto3/AWS CLI command to do this, however. I see there is 'update_product', but there doesn't appear to be a way to use this command specify a version number,nor do I think there is a way to remove deprecated versions without removing the product itself with 'delete_product'.

Is there a way to do this versioning from the CLI?

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the Product ID of the product you wish to update by using the command below, and note the value of the field named *ProductId*

   `aws servicecatalog search-products-as-admin`
2. Upload the CloudFormation template to S3 and copy the URL to the template
3. Run the following command, inserting the Version Name, Product ID and the URL for the template in S3

   `aws servicecatalog create-provisioning-artifact --product-id INSERT_PRODUCT_ID --parameters Name=INSERT_VERSION_NAME,Info={LoadTemplateFromURL=INSERT_TEMPLATE_URL},Type=CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE`

Answer (score 0):

Use `aws servicecatalog generate provisioning-artifact`.

Answer (score -1):

Hope these AWS S3 url's for AWS CLI options are of some help to you:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-versioning.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration.html

Comment: My question is not about S3, but about Service Catalog. I've done some of my own digging and opened a case to Amazon, who confirm that it is not currently a feature, and that update_product is strictly for changing the metadata. Looks like my only option is to replace the product entirely.